# How do we convert an object to application/x-www-form-urlencoded in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am trying to perform a login using post method in angular 4 application that requires the url and an  application/x-www-form-urlencoded data(in body not header).

I found this function in a similar post for angularjs but this doesn't seem to work on Angular v4

```
var str = [];
for (var key in obj) {
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
str.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]))                  
console.log(key + " -> " + obj[key]);
}}
return str.join("&");
```

Angular Official Documentation have removed the link https://angular.io/api/http/BaseRequestOptions-class , nor the previously supported Query-String import is available.

I wish to know if there's any other method or module that we could use.

Comment: Would you want this? https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams

Comment: Actually i am looking for a conversion module from object (eg: JSON) to formencoded format. earlier in angularjs2, i used to perform this using query-string but the same is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform an application/x-www-form-urlencoded post request and store the object in the body of the request, this works.

```
post(data) {
    let options = new DefaultRequestOptions();
        let params = new URLSearchParams("");

        for (var key in data) {
           if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              params.append(key, data[key])
           }
        }

        this.http.post('some url', params , options);
}
```

Otherwise, you can send the data via the url directly from header options.